# Gridview Edit Item using Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am using ASP.NET Gridview and Oracle 9i data to display in it. I have a joining condition of `Zone No` from Table Zones . I used the DropdownList to display the `Zone Names` and returning its value to update in GridView but when I update the grid it display error

> 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

I have attached the the Dropdown with DB Table Now My Complete code for tamplate for Zone_no is here

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zone No" SortExpression="ZONE_NO">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="157px" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  SelectedValue='<%# BIND("ZONE_NO") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ZONE_DESC" DataValueField="ZONE_NO"> 
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand='SELECT DISTINCT "ZONE_NO", "ZONE_DESC",NULL FROM "MLK_00_05" ORDER BY "ZONE_DESC", "ZONE_NO"'>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZONE_NO") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: When I press the edit button from gridview then above error is diplayed.

Comment: It says that bind expression value is not found in dropdown items collection. You should have to specify value attribute of dropdownlist.

Comment: Sir Please Check  the update in question

Comment: Sir I have updated my complete question please see it and answer my question

Comment: I'm sure that the datasource bound with GridView has ZONE_NO value which is not  present in MLK_00_05 table - SqlDataSource3. Please post full code and verify the value of ZONE_NO in both these tables.